# Generate documentation from POJO with Java Bean Validation annotations

Tags: java, javadoc, bean-validation

We have existing beans that are generated from XSD with JAXB.
There are a lot (really) of XSD files so compilation for that part takes some time. We have a custom Maven plugin that generates an HTML catalog of all the beans by reading the XSDs.

We'd like to get rid of JAXB because the documentation in the XSD is not kept in the generated bean and some constraints expressed in XML are not properly translated to Java or not enforced strongly enough.

We want to use Java Bean Validation annotations (with custom ones when necessary).

Do you know about an existing plugin/library/whatever that would merge existing Javadoc comments with generated documentation from Java Bean Validation annotations?

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

/**
 * Documentation...
 */
@Getter
@Setter
public class Bean {

    /**
     * Documentation with javadoc annotations
     */
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
    private String message;

}
```

For example, for the message property the documentation would look like:

> Documentation with javadoc annotations
>   "message" should not be null.
>   "message" size must be between 3 and 20 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bean Validation constraint annotations are already part of generated JavaDoc (or any annotation really which is meta-annotated with `@Documented`). If that's not enough, you could consider to write a custom doclet which adds a textual representation of that constraint metadata.

Comment: Btw. someone in the Hibernate forum [mentioned](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1044569) that he's working on a doclet along these lines. I'm not sure whether he ever published his work, I've just asked in the forum again.

Comment: It seems like the @Documented annotation translates to annotations being copied to the generated HTML Javadoc. `@NotNull
 @Size(min=3,
      max=20)
private String message
Documentation with javadoc annotations`. I would prefer to see text.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant to say above :)

Comment: I'm the author of the taglet that Gunnar mentions. I will proceed, in my spare time, to move this towards release. It won't be quickly. The taglet produces an html table that lists the property and its constraint, one for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You should try JAutoDoc plugin for generating Javadoc (eclipse, STS,..). It has choices for generating: replace existing, complete existing, keep existing. On top of that, you can custom various choice.
Link marketplace: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jautodoc

Comment: Unfortunately Eclipse plugin is not an option. I know I said "whatever". It is whatever except Eclipse stuff ;-). I'd like something which is IDE agnostic (which can run on build server and such).